# Declarar de manera correcta una matriz

Tags: python

**PREGUNTA EDITADA, la primera vez había enfocado mal el caso**

Quiero trabajar con matrices pero no consigo entender como hacerlo. Quiero que cada vez que haga click con el ratón guardar las posiciones X e Y de su posición.

Para ello quería crear una matriz. Con el primer click guardar las coordenadas en `matriz[0][0]` y `matriz[0][1]`, con el segundo click guardarlas en `matriz[1][0]` y `matriz[1][1]`

Para ello he creado este código

```
def buscar_circulos(event,x,y,flags,param):

global cont

global posicionAnterior

if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP and cont == False:
    posicionAnterior[0][0] = x
    posicionAnterior[0][1] = y
    cont = True

elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP and cont == True:
    posicionAnterior[1][0] = x
    posicionAnterior[1][1] = y

    print('Valor posicionAnterior[0][0]: ',posicionAnterior[0][0])
    print('Valor posicionAnterior[0][1]: ',posicionAnterior[0][1])
    print('Valor posicionAnterior[1][0]: ',posicionAnterior[1][0])
    print('Valor posicionAnterior[1][1]: ',posicionAnterior[1][1])
```

Decir que cont es una global inicializada como `cont = False` y posicionAnterior como `posicionAnterior = [[],[]]`

He probado también con `.append()`, por ejemplo `posicionAnterior[0][0].append(x)` y tampoco consigo nada. (creo que esto es más correcto que lo que tengo en el código)

Entiendo que no debo estar declarando bien la matriz, pero no entiendo el motivo.

Comment: En principio te falta el `=` en la linea `posicionAnterior [[],[]]`, debería ser algo así `posicionAnterior = [[None, None],[None, None]]` . Si no inicializas los elementos de la lista no puedes luego indexar, `[0][0]` no existe en la matriz `[[],[]]` porque las filas son listas vacías. Si quieres conservar los valores de `posicionAnterior` entre llamadas debes inicializarla globalmente no en la función cada vez que es llamada.

Comment: @FJSevilla si perdona, justo estaba editando la pregunta

Comment: Debes inicializar los elementos como comento arriba cuando defines la lista, a `None` o a `0` (`posicionAnterior = [0, 0], [0, 0]`) o a lo que te convenga, esto es lo más apropiado dado que tu lista tiene dimensiones fijas y conocidas.  Si incializas con  `[[], []]` usa `append` pero esto es incorrecto: `posicionAnterior[0][0].append(x)`, debe ser `posicionAnterior[0].append(x)`, `append` no asigna valores añade un item al final de la lista, en este caso añade `x` a la lista en el índice `0` de `posicionAnterior` (primera fila).

Comment: Agregando a lo que ya dijeron anteriormente, recuerda que en Python no existen las matrices. Existen listas, tuplas, diccionarios; que en el caso de las listas pueden servir para simular matrices, pero son mucho más potentes que un simple almacén de datos, por lo cual hay que inicializarlas correctamente dependiendo de para qué se van a usar.
posicionAnterior = [[0, 0],[0, 0]]